# send value from controller to route

Tags: ember.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("cases");
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        login: function() {           
            transitionToRoute('cases','data1','data2');//send data to case
         }
    }
});


App.CasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(xxx1,xxx2) {
        //get 'data'
        alert(xxx1);
    }
});
```

I want send some data from IndexController to model in CaseRoute, i am beginner and read [this](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/redirection/) but i does not understand.
This way for send value to model is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct way to pass parameters to route (alternative way: query parameters). Your code needs some corrections:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("cases", { path: '/cases/:data1/:data2' });
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function() {           
        this.transitionToRoute('cases','data1','data2');
     }
  }
});

App.CasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    //use params.data1 to get 'data1'
    console.log("data1", params.data1);
    console.log("data2", params.data2);
  }
});
```